# Как перейти на следующий элемент внешнего цикла?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Когда идет отсчёт в основном цикле, нужно произвести поиск по 3 массивам, которые объявляются ранее. Если элемент был найден уже в первом вложенном цикле, то поиск по следующим двум всё равно происходит. Как это предотвратить и перейти на следующий элемент внешнего цикла?
Например:

```
for i := 0 to length(ar_mas) do
begin
 for j := 0 to length(k_mas) do
 begin
   <действие>
   break;
 end;
 for j := 0 to length(raz_mas) do
 begin
   <действие>
   break;
 end;
 for j := 0 to length(id_mas) do
 begin
   <действие>
   break;
 end;
end;
```

В <действие> ничего существенного не происходит, кроме как запись в stringGrid и поиск в массивах

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый простой вариант: завести флаг (булевую переменную), и устанавливать его, если элемент найден, в начале каждой итерации внешнего цикла сбрасывать:

```
for i := 0 to length(ar_mas) do
begin
    flag := False;
    for j := 0 to length(k_mas) do
    begin
        if %условие% then begin
            <действие>
            flag = True;
            break;
        end;
    end;
    if not flag then begin
        for j := 0 to length(raz_mas) do
        begin
            if %условие% then begin
                <действие>
                flag = True;
                break;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    if not flag then begin
        for j := 0 to length(id_mas) do
        begin
            if %условие% then begin
                <действие>
                flag = True;
                break;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Можно еще использовать [`goto`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_goto_statement.htm):

```
var
    ...
label
    L;

....
for i := 0 to length(ar_mas) do
begin
    for j := 0 to length(k_mas) do
    begin
        if %условие% then begin
            <действие>
            goto L; // в двух остальных то же самое
        end;
    end;
    ...
    L: // это в самом конце тела внешнего цикла
end;
```

Comment: Третий способ в копилку (он лучше чем goto) - raise TMyException

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, не совсем правильный цикл по массиву `for i := 0 to length(ar_mas) do` - может привести к AV, если внутри будет обращение к элементам массива по индексу из цикла. Надо `for i := 0 to length(ar_mas) - 1 do`.
В дополнении к ответу [Flownee](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178678/flowneee), в качестве флага, можно использовать проверку `if j = length(k_mas) - 1 then ...`

Comment: Проверка на `>=` надёжнее.